# Парсинг HTML на Python + bs4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, bs4

Требуется отпарсить часть HTML

```
[
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.19</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.49</div>,
    <divstyle="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.59</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.64</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.43</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.63</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.58</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.39</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.49</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.36</div>,
    <div style="width:40%;/* float: left; */">2.41</div>,
    <div style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */">2.59</div>
]
```

Так, чтобы получить значения между div-ами (2.19 [...] 2.49)

UPD: Добавлен код для загрузки HTML страницы.

Доведя код до простоты выйдет так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('https://taripebi.ge/%E1%83%91%E1%83%94%E1%83%9C%E1%83%96%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1-%E1%83%A4%E1%83%90%E1%83%A1%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98')

scraping_html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
find_by_attr = scraping_html.find_all('div', attrs={'style':'width: 40%;/* float: left; */'})
print(find_by_attr)
```

Comment: Если у Вас все настолько просто, то можно использовать и регекспы (модуль re). Но в целом - это подход неправильный. Есть модули, позволяющие парсить всю html-страницу целиком, без промежуточных элементов, как в вопросе. Про BeautifulSoup Вы и так знаете, вот его и используйте по-полной

Comment: Я так понимаю, список получен при помощи bs4?  Я бы на Вашем месте привёл в вопросе кусок исходного html файла, кусок кода с bs4, получающего список, и спросил, как этот код улучшить

Comment: Обновил и добавил в вопрос упрощенный код без декораторов, комментариев и пометок.

Comment: Отлично, не могу проверить сам, попробуйте добавить `.text` в конце вызова `find_all()`. Как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11709155/9921853)

Comment: Черт. Все гениальное - просто. Правда там на выходе дает список и нужно в цикле пробежаться, а так все работает. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цифры были получены после ответа @sergey-nudnov

Достаточно было пробежаться циклом и добавить `.text`

```
for item in find_by_attr:
      print(item.text)
```

Comment: Отлично. Проплюсовал :)